# Is it possible to generate cookie which seems to be generated by js file - scraping problem

Tags: javascript, cookies, screen-scraping, incapsula

I am trying to scrape a website which seems to generate cookies from js somehow, therefore I can not automate scraping. Any help is really appreciated.

I am checking cookies of Firefox with SQLLite, and I see 5 cookies.
But when I check in Firefox Developer Tools Inspect I see that 7 cookies are used in each request.

It turns out these 2 cookies are very important and the website doesn't respond to my Python scraper unless I provide all of the cookies.

These cookies are created by Incapsula - a security third party application, and both of them are incap_ses.

My question is?
Where I can access those cookies or is it possible to generate them on my own?
Should I keep digging js files to find some function that generates those cookies, or it is meaningless?